# Does $\int_{-\infty }^{\ln \pi} \sqrt{\sin e^t} \, \rm{d}t$ have closed form?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

##### Background

I am studying the area of the implicit function curve

$$y^2=\sin \left(e^x\right).$$

I found that I need to calculate this integral:

$$I=\int_{-\infty }^{\ln \pi} \sqrt{\sin e^t} \, \rm{d}t.$$

##### Try 1

let $t = \sin e^x$, then

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{1-t^2} }\frac{1}{\arcsin t}\,\rm{d}t$$

I can't figure out how to calculate this.

##### Try 2

let $t = e^x$, then

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sqrt{\sin (t)}}{t}\,\rm{d}t$$

This form looks simple, but I still don't know how to calculate.

##### Question

Does $I$ have closed form?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it doesn't have a closed form for the abstract integral. The numerical integral (on the specific interval) is a bit trickier

Comment: @hellofriends. As an infinite series, no problem.

Comment: It is also equal to: $$\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{x(\pi-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{x(\pi-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$If this proves useful I will add my derivation. I chose to push this representation because I think it’s more amenable to contour integration with more roots on the denominator but I’m not sure how to use this.

Comment: Out of curiosity did you derive the implicit form from a set of parametric equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote
$$I=\int_{-\infty }^{\log(  \pi)} \sqrt{\sin (e^t)} \, dt=\int_{0 }^{\pi}\frac{\sqrt{\sin (x)}}{x}\,dx$$

Using series expansion
$$\sqrt{\sin (x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{b_n} x^{2 n+\frac{1}{2}} $$ The $a_n$ form the sequence $A008991$ and the $b_n$ form the sequence $A008992$ is $OEIS$.

So
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{\sin (x)}}{x}\,dx=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{(4n+1)\,b_n} x^{2 n+\frac{1}{2}}$$

The convergence is very slow

**Edit**

None of the CAS I was able to use gave the antiderivative or the integral. However, using the $\large 1,400$ years old approximation
$$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad (0\leq x\leq\pi)$$ proposed by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician we can write
$$\frac{\sqrt{\sin (x)}}{x} \simeq 2 \sqrt{\frac{(\pi -x)}{x (x-a) (x-b)}}\quad \text{with} \quad a=\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\right) \pi\quad \text{and} \quad b=\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right) \pi$$ which can be integrated using elliptic integrals of the first and third kinds.

Just a few numbers for

$$I_k=\int_0^{k\frac{\pi}{12}}\frac{\sqrt{\sin (x)}}{x}\,dx$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \text{approximation}& \text{solution} \\
 1 & 1.02920 & 1.02216 \\
 2 & 1.44820 & 1.44060 \\
 3 & 1.76172 & 1.75428 \\
 4 & 2.01665 & 2.00943 \\
 5 & 2.23049 & 2.22336 \\
 6 & 2.41171 & 2.40459 \\
 7 & 2.56500 & 2.55789 \\
 8 & 2.69317 & 2.68612 \\
 9 & 2.79790 & 2.79094 \\
 10 & 2.87997 & 2.87305 \\
 11 & 2.93881 & 2.93182 \\
 12 & 2.96882 & 2.96169
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: @metamorphy. Thanks for pointing my stupidity. Cheers :-(

Comment: Oh yes, $2\pi$ is a mistake

Comment: Do the OEIS formulas have explicit forms?

Answer (score 0):

Another *not-an-answer* regarding the computational matter. As commented, $$I=\int_0^\pi\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{x}\,dx=\int_0^\pi\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\pi-x}\,dx
=\frac\pi2\int_0^\pi\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{x(\pi-x)}\,dx$$ which becomes, after the substitution $x=(1+t)\pi/2$, $$I=\int_{-1}^1\frac{f(t)\,dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}},\qquad f(t)=\sqrt{\frac1{1-t^2}\cos\frac{\pi t}2}.$$ This choice of $f(t)$ "eats out" the singularities at $t=\pm1$, so that $$f(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n\,t^{2n}\implies I=\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}f_n,$$ and the radius of convergence of the power series equals $3$, so that $f_n\sim 9^{-n}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Thus $I_N:=\pi\sum_{n=0}^N(\ldots)$ are approximations of the given integral:
\begin{align*}
I_0&=\pi,\\
I_1&=\frac{5\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi^3}{32},\\
I_2&=\frac{89\pi}{64}-\frac{11\pi^3}{256}-\frac{\pi^5}{4096},\\
I_3&=\frac{381\pi}{256}-\frac{103\pi^3}{2048}-\frac{17\pi^5}{49152}-\frac{19\pi^7}{1179648},
\end{align*}
and $I_{35}=2.96168593796665631486155938224615651\ldots$ (with these digits correct).

Still, this rate of convergence is *much* slower than what [double-exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanh-sinh_quadrature) methods give.